# NSScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet gives BAD ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsscanner

```
NSString*test=[NSString stringWithString:inputString]; 
NSScanner*scan;
BOOL pass= [scan scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] intoString:&test];
```

The last line crashes the app with bad access. Does it have something to do with the address symbol, `&`? I'm not clear on why it needs this type of syntax anyway.

I am trying to simply check with my BOOL if the `inputString` contains any non-alphanumeric characters. If it does, `pass` becomes YES.

UPDATE: I see I do not understand scanner entirely. I understand this output:

```
NSString*test=@"Hello"; // this should cause my BOOL to be NO since no characters are scanned
NSScanner*scanix=[NSScanner scannerWithString:test];
BOOL pass= [scanix scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] intoString:nil];
NSLog(@"pass is %i for %@",pass, test);
```

Result in log: `pass is 1 for Hello`

What I want is to know if in fact the test string contains non-alphanumeric characters. How would I factor such a test into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to know if in fact the test string contains
>   non-alphanumeric characters. How would I factor such a test into this?

You don't need to use NSScanner if this is your only goal. You can simply use NSString's `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` method:

```
NSCharacterSet *nonAlphanumeric = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
pass = ([test rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonAlphanumeric].location != NSNotFound);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to initialise your scanner with the string to parse,

```
    NSScanner *scan =[NSScanner scannerWithString:mystring];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the destination string and the source string. Your source is `test`. Also, your scanner is not initialized.

```
NSScanner *scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:test];
BOOL didScanCharacters = [scan scanUpToCharactersFromSet:
   [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet] 
   intoString:nil];
```

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs because you are sending a message to a nonexistent object.

Comment: No, the result should be `YES`. There **are** alphanumeric characters in the string "Hello".

Comment: You read before I deleted, sorry; I updated my question with my real goal. Note that I am scanning for the inverted set, so looking for the non-alphanumeric.

Comment: You can use `NSScanner`'s `setCharactersToBeSkipped:`. Set this property to the alphanumeric character set.